# Add cookie to wordpress wp-json api call

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am developing an app for iPhone that makes use of a Wordpress site as a backend. I am also making changes to the site and have created basic endpoints for servicing the app using the Wordpress wp-json restful api. I have installed the JSON API, JSON API Auth, and JSON API User plugins and support user authentication. I manage to login a user and get a session token while doing so, a cookie. How do I make the subsequent calls authenticated, i.e. how do I add the cookie as a required parameter to an existing endpoint?

For instance, I have this code that retrieves the latest menu for the week:

```
function get_latest_menu ( $params ){
            $post = get_posts( array(
              'category'      => 69,
                'posts_per_page'  => 1,
                'offset'      => 0
          ) );

            if( empty( $post ) ){
                return null;
            }

            return $post[0]->post_content;
         }

         // Register the rest route here.

         add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

                 register_rest_route( 'weeks-menu/v1', 'latest-menu',array(

                     'methods'  => 'GET',
                     'callback' => 'get_latest_menu'

                 ) );

          } );
```

Where and how should I add the cookie parameter in the call so that it would become authenticated? Please provide specific code if possible.

This might seem quite basic but I have no real php/Wordpress knowledge
nor the time to acquire it. Thank you.

Comment: The [description page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/) of the JSON API Auth plugin pretty much tells you what you need to do to pass the auth cookie to your custom controllers/endpoints.

Comment: No it doesn't. It just shows how to pass the cookie to the getCurrentUserInfo call which he also provides. I would like to know how to apply this to my own api calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much help this will be after the fact but recently for school I ran into a similar issue while developing a mobile application using Ionic. The things I had to do were:

1. Enable Authentication headers in the HTAccess file for wordpress (it usually fails if you do not do this, the docs for the JWT explain exactly what to add and it worked for me).
2. I used post man to test it but the first thing you do is get the token for the username / password.
3. Every subsequent call you add an authorization flag in the header in the form `Authorization: Bearer <token>` where  is your token you had for the user. I had a package with Ionic that can force the token from my storage which worked every time I made a call.

Additionally, you can add a new check to verify if the token is valid but there are a few plugins that force any rest end point to be authenticated which ends up sending an unauthorized flag which you can check in your code.

My recommendation if your still unclear download and use postman and use it to verify if everything is set up correctly. Once you get that sorted everything else starts making more sense.